# Fragment Error with Parse

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform

I am using tabs to do a project. I am getting the following error. attach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (com.outdeh.EventsFragment).

```
package com.outdeh;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.PushService;


public class EventsFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


        // Parse.initialize(this, "nSXPAwYG29VZMaCkasdjhakhsdkjsahdhj", "PWeiawu25r7sAmOYdgP0kajhsdkahaskjdhashj");

       // ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        //testObject.put("foo", "bar new");
        //testObject.saveInBackground();

    }

    public EventsFragment() {
        //Required empty public constructor
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_fragment, container, false);
    }
}






package com.outdeh;

import com.outdeh.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.PushService;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    TabHost tHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Push notifications
        Parse.initialize(this, "nSXPAwYG29VZMdfsddfsdfsdfdselz", "PWeiawu25r7sAmOYddfdsfsdfsdfssVkSJJEWU");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        // Save the current Installation to Parse.
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();


        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tHost.setup();

        /** Defining Tab Change Listener event. This is invoked when tab is changed */
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm =   getSupportFragmentManager();
                HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("outdeh");
                EventsFragment eventsFragment = (EventsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("events");
                PicsFragment picsFragment = (PicsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("pics");
                NewsFragment newsFragment = (NewsFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("news");
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                /** Detaches the homeFragment if exists */
                if(homeFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(homeFragment);

                /** Detaches the eventsFragment if exists*/
                 if(eventsFragment!=null)
                 ft.detach(eventsFragment);

                /** Detaches the newsFragment if exists */
                if(newsFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(newsFragment);

                /** Detaches the picsFragment if exists */
                if(picsFragment!=null)
                    ft.detach(picsFragment);


                /** If current tab is android */
                if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("outdeh")){

                    if(homeFragment==null){
                        /** Create homeFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new HomeFragment(), "outdeh");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(homeFragment);
                    }

                }else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("events")){

                    if(eventsFragment==null){
                        /** Create homeFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new EventsFragment(), "events");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(eventsFragment);
                    }

                }else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("news")){

                    if(newsFragment==null){
                        /** Create homeFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new NewsFragment(), "news");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(newsFragment);
                    }

                }else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("pics")){

                    if(picsFragment==null){
                        /** Create homeFragment and adding to fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent,new PicsFragment(), "pics");
                    }else{
                        /** Bring to the front, if already exists in the fragmenttransaction */
                        ft.attach(picsFragment);
                    }

                }
                ft.commit();
            }
        };


        /** Setting tabchangelistener for the tab */
        tHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);

        /** Defining tab builder for Home tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecOutdeh = tHost.newTabSpec("outdeh");
        tSpecOutdeh.setIndicator("OutDeh",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
        tSpecOutdeh.setContent(new DefinedTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecOutdeh);


        /** Defining tab builder for Events tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecEvents = tHost.newTabSpec("events");
        tSpecEvents.setIndicator("Upcoming Events",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.events));
        tSpecEvents.setContent(new DefinedTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecEvents);

        /** Defining tab builder for Pics tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecPics = tHost.newTabSpec("pics");
        tSpecPics.setIndicator("Recent Event Pictures",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pics));
        tSpecPics.setContent(new DefinedTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecPics);

        /** Defining tab builder for News tab */
        TabHost.TabSpec tSpecNews = tHost.newTabSpec("news");
        tSpecNews.setIndicator("Entertainment News",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.news));
        tSpecNews.setContent(new DefinedTabContent(getBaseContext()));
        tHost.addTab(tSpecNews);

    }

}
```

//Next Class Below

---

When I run this, I get the following error.

```
inconvertible types
found   : android.support.v4.app.Fragment
required: com.outdeh.EventsFragment


detach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (com.outdeh.EventsFragment)

cannot find symbol method add(int,com.outdeh.EventsFragment,java.lang.String)

attach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (com.outdeh.EventsFragment)
```

Comment: does your `EventsFragment` extend `Fragments`

Comment: Its better you post your code here. So it's easy to help

Answer (score 1):

This means that your EventsFragment need to implement FragmentTransaction:

considering your exception: `attach(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be (com.outdeh.EventsFragment)`

probably using `getFragmentManager()`, change to `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

Usually such errors are caused when you are not using the support library in all Fragments.

Saying that, please check and ensure that all your references to Fragment, FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction are from the support library only and not the other one. Also, your calls to FragmentManager should be using getSupportFragmentManager().

This should resolve the issue. If thats not the case and you are using the correct imports then please post your code.